# Exception in agent.runonserver in lotus notes

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotusscript, lotus, lotus-formula

I have the code which calls java agent from lotusscript agent

```
Sub insertDealDetails() 
    On Error GoTo errhandler
    MsgBox "inside deal details"
    Dim agent As NotesAgent
    On Error GoTo errhandler
    Set agent = db.GetAgent("Procs")
    If agent.RunOnServer(doc.Noteid) = 0 Then
        MessageBox "Agent ran",, "Success"
    Else
        MessageBox "Agent did not run",, "Failure"
    End If
    Exit Sub

errhandler:
    MsgBox  "Error in function insertDealDetails in agtSubmit Agent" & Erl & Error

End Sub
```

Now if any exception occurs in `Procs` agent,how the main agent calling `insertDealDetails()` can be supplied with exception so that it stops the main agent.

Comment: What about writing the error in your java agent in the document "doc" and retrieving it after the run...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an [In-Memory Document](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/dx/XPages_and_Calling_Agents_Using_an_In-Memory_Document),
write your error message into this document in Java agent and
read the error message in LotusScript code.

LotusScript

```
Call agent.RunWithDocumentContext(doc)
If doc.ErrorMessage(0) <> "" Then
    print doc.ErrorMessage(0)
    ' handle the error
End If
```

Java agent

```
Document doc = agentContext.getDocumentContext();
...
doc.replaceItemValue("ErrorMessage", "Your Error Message from Java Agent");
```

You don't need to save the In-Memory document at any time.

Comment: For curiousity,If the time taken by Java agent is more for showing exception,will this error check in lotus agent get bypassed,as I believe that these will be parallel threads getting executed??

Comment: No, LotusScript agent waits until Java agent has finished. RunWithDocumentContext() call is synchronous.

Comment: Thanks a lot Knut...you saved my day...Will implement it today.. 

Comment: Knut,thanks for the valuable information...and its done.  

Comment: The argument passed in runwithdocumentcontext is a newly created doc or previous context doc made in lotus agent?

Comment: Usually it's a newly created doc which is only used for "transporting" data between both agents and never gets saved.

Comment: Thanks for it.actually i have pasted the recent code of mine but its not working,will u see and tell me the problem

Answer (score 0):

it is updated code

```
`Sub insertDealDetails() 
    On Error GoTo errhandler
    MsgBox "inside deal details"
    Dim agent As NotesAgent
    Dim in_doc As Notesdocument
    On Error GoTo errhandler
    Set agent = db.GetAgent("Procs")
    Set in_doc = db.createDocument()
    If agent.Runwithdocumentcontext(in_doc,doc.Noteid) Then`
        MsgBox "doc.ErrorMessage(0):::::::::"&in_doc.ErrorMessage(0)
        If in_doc.ErrorMessage(0)<>"" Then
            Call prompt("2")
        End If
    End If

Exit Sub
errhandler:
    MsgBox  "Error in function insertDealDetails in agtSubmit Agent" & Erl & Error

End Sub
```

the problem now here is it is not returning from java code called in `Procs` agent.What i will be doing wrong here.

```
public class JavaAgent extends AgentBase {


    public void NotesMain() {
        Connection con = null;
        CallableStatement stmt = null;
        Database db;
        lotus.domino.Document doc = null;
        try {
            Session session = getSession();
            AgentContext agentContext = session.getAgentContext();
            doc = agentContext.getDocumentContext();
            con = JavaAgent.getConnection(); //making connectiion here
            //executing code here and exception occurs
            System.out.println("success");

        } catch(Exception e) {
            try {
                doc.replaceItemValue("ErrorMessage", e.getMessage());
            } catch (NotesException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally{
            try {
                stmt.close();
                con.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                try {
                    doc.replaceItemValue("ErrorMessage", e.getMessage());
                } catch (NotesException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The logs for the same is as follows:

```
**[0DCC:01AD-053C] 01/27/2016 01:24:56 PM  HTTP JVM: class load: JavaAgent from: <unknown>
[0DCC:04B2-199C] 01/27/2016 01:24:56 PM  HTTP JVM: before connection:::::
[0DCC:04B2-199C] 01/27/2016 01:24:56 PM  HTTP JVM: inside dobi
[0DCC:04B2-199C] 01/27/2016 01:24:56 PM  HTTP JVM: inside dobi 2
[0DCC:04B2-199C] 01/27/2016 01:25:28 PM  HTTP JVM: inside dobi 3
[0DCC:04B2-199C] 01/27/2016 01:25:28 PM  HTTP JVM: after connection:::::Oracle Database 11g Release 11.1.0.0.0 - Production
[0DCC:04B2-199C] 01/27/2016 01:25:28 PM  HTTP JVM: message is Invalid column index
[0DCC:04B2-199C] 01/27/2016 01:25:28 PM  HTTP JVM: java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column index
[0DCC:04B2-199C] 01/27/2016 01:25:28 PM  HTTP JVM:  at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:125)
[0DCC:04B2-199C] 01/27/2016 01:25:28 PM  HTTP JVM:  at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:162)
[0DCC:04B2-199C] 01/27/2016 01:25:28 PM  HTTP JVM:  at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:227)
[0DCC:04B2-199C] 01/27/2016 01:25:28 PM  HTTP JVM:  at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.setStringInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:4596)
[0DCC:04B2-199C] 01/27/2016 01:25:28 PM  HTTP JVM:  at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleCallableStatement.setString(OracleCallableStatement.java:4249)
[0DCC:04B2-199C] 01/27/2016 01:25:28 PM  HTTP JVM:  at JavaAgent.NotesMain(Unknown Source)
[0DCC:04B2-199C] 01/27/2016 01:25:28 PM  HTTP JVM:  at lotus.domino.AgentBase.runNotes(Unknown Source)
[0DCC:04B2-199C] 01/27/2016 01:25:28 PM  HTTP JVM:  at lotus.domino.NotesThread.run(Unknown Source)
[0DF8:000A-0F84] Router: DNS server returned an error searching for MX records. The destination domain may not exist: 11.17.108.223, Error: Not implemented(NOTIMP)**
```

Comment: Just write `call agent.Runwithdocumentcontext(in_doc,doc.Noteid)` without testing return code. It seems to return `false` that's why you don't see MsgBox Output.

Comment: Yes Krut,its working perfectly fine now.It returned false value.Will share the updated code same here.Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

The working code with steps for the same is as follows:

```
%REM
    Sub insertDetailsOracle
    Description: To insert details in Oracle Table
    Date: 28/03/2014

    '******************* Logic ***************************
    'Validation In submit agent
    '1)Create in-memory document
    '2)Run java agent with Runwithdocumentcontext passing newly created  in-memory document 
    '  as well as note-id of original request document context

    'If pass i.e. no exceptions in Java agent
    '1) submit the Case

     'Else
     '1) Log Error message and exit the agent

    '***************************************************

%END REM

Function  insertDetailsOracle() As String 
    On Error GoTo errhandler
    Dim agent As NotesAgent
    Dim agentValue As Boolean

    Set agent = db.GetAgent("Procs")

    'Create in-memory document
    Set in_doc = db.createDocument()

    'Running java agent with Runwithdocumentcontext
    agentValue = agent.Runwithdocumentcontext(in_doc,doc.Noteid)

    'Return error message as per message passed by java agent in in-memory document's field
    If in_doc.ErrorMessage(0)<>"" Then
        insertDealDetails = in_doc.ErrorMessage(0)
    Else
        insertDealDetails = "1"
    End If

    Exit Function
errhandler:
    MsgBox  "Error in function insertDealDetailsOracle in agtSubmit Agent" & Erl & Error
End Function
```

The java method will be same as below.